# com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.BusyPoolException

Tags: cassandra, datastax

Whenever I insert data in table in Cassandra, more than 1000 and fetching the data by id, it throws the following exception:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.BusyPoolException: [localhost/127.0.0.1] Pool is busy (no available connection and the queue has reached its max size 256)))
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.reportNoMoreHosts(RequestHandler.java:213)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.access$1000(RequestHandler.java:49)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.findNextHostAndQuery(RequestHandler.java:277)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution$1.onFailure(RequestHandler.java:340)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:1764)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:456)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$ImmediateFuture.addListener(Futures.java:153)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.addCallback(Futures.java:1776)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.addCallback(Futures.java:1713)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.query(RequestHandler.java:299)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.findNextHostAndQuery(RequestHandler.java:274)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.startNewExecution(RequestHandler.java:117)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.sendRequest(RequestHandler.java:97)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.executeAsync(SessionManager.java:132)
    at com.outworkers.phantom.builder.query.CassandraOperations$class.scalaQueryStringToPromise(CassandraOperations.scala:67)
    at com.outworkers.phantom.builder.query.InsertQuery.scalaQueryStringToPromise(InsertQuery.scala:31)
    at com.outworkers.phantom.builder.query.CassandraOperations$class.scalaQueryStringExecuteToFuture(CassandraOperations.scala:31)
    at com.outworkers.phantom.builder.query.InsertQuery.scalaQueryStringExecuteToFuture(InsertQuery.scala:31)
    at com.outworkers.phantom.builder.query.ExecutableStatement$class.future(ExecutableQuery.scala:80)
    at com.outworkers.phantom.builder.query.InsertQuery.future(InsertQuery.scala:31)
    at nd.cluster.data.store.Points.upsert(Models.scala:114)
```

I have solved above issue using PoolingOptions.

```
val poolingOptions = new PoolingOptions()
    .setConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL, 1, 200)
    .setMaxRequestsPerConnection(HostDistance.LOCAL, 256)
    .setNewConnectionThreshold(HostDistance.LOCAL, 100).setCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL, 200)

  val builder1 =  ContactPoint.local
    .noHeartbeat()
    .withClusterBuilder(_.withoutJMXReporting()
      .withoutMetrics().withPoolingOptions(poolingOptions)).keySpace("nd")
```

Now it is working even with 1l data. But i am not sure about its efficiency.
Could anyone please help me ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This means that you are submitting too many requests, and not waiting for the futures to complete before submitting more.

The default maximum number of requests per connection is 1024. If this number is exceeded for all connections, the connection pool will enqueue some requests, up to 256. If the queue gets full, a BusyPoolException is thrown.   Of course you can increase the max number of requests per connection, and the number of max connections per host. But the real solution is of course to throttle your thread. You could e.g. submit your requests by batches of 1,000 and then wait on the futures to complete before submitting more, or use a semaphore to regulate the total number of pending requests and make sure they don't exceed a certain number (in theory, this number must stay below num_hosts * max_connections_per_host * max_requests_per_connection – in practice, I don't suggest going above 1,000 as it probably won't bring you more throughput).

You may find this links useful.

https://github.com/redisson/redisson/issues/438
https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!topic/java-driver-user/p3CwOL0kNrs  http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/pooling

Comment: I have read already those forums. But i didn't get it how to throttle. So i solved the issue using poolingoption.

Comment: @MaheshChandKandpal Throttling example with semaphore  https://stackoverflow.com/a/30526719/5940335