# Handle correctly a big number of asynchronous queries

Tags: java, cassandra

I have to update several thousand of records in a Cassandra table and I use `executeAsync(BoundStatement)` method however I got the error `Pool is busy (no available connection and the queue has reached its max size 256)` see below the full details.$

What is the best way to correctly handle this type of execution? What about increasing the Cassandra query queue size and the wait time in the queue?

```
Exception in thread "Thread-6" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: cassandra2/172.18.0.17:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.BusyPoolException: [cassandra2/172.18.0.17] Pool is busy (no available connection and the queue has reached its max size 256)), cassandra4/172.18.0.18:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.BusyPoolException: [cassandra4/172.18.0.18] Pool is busy (no available connection and the queue has reached its max size 256)), cassandra1/172.18.0.11:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.BusyPoolException: [cassandra1/172.18.0.11] Pool is busy (no available connection and the queue has reached its max size 256)))
at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException.copy(NoHostAvailableException.java:75)
at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException.copy(NoHostAvailableException.java:28)
at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:28)
at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:236)
```

I use a cluster with 3 nodes, QUORUM consistency and replication factor of 3.

Comment: suggestion:  catch exception and try again

Comment: if there is too much load it can be retried almost infinitely since it fails too often. For example if you try to execute several batches of 1k updates for a queue of 256 elements it will fail almost directly and you don't know what are the executed queries and the failed one to exclude the success in your retry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Tune the [connection pool](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/pooling/) to achieve maximum performance for your cluster
2. Throttle the number of async queries to avoid NoHostAvailableException. E.g. as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30526719/5940335)

Answer (score 2):

You could increase your queue but that really just puts off the problem. You probably would want to just retry any such requests but it may be in your best interests to use a semaphore and only permit a certain number of requests to be inflight at a time rather than queueing up all the inserts at once.

You could also use a mechanism like this if ordering is important

Spark Cassandra Connector [slidingIteartor](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/0369a7b304542a552c4c959f8e8bb0ac3ebcbd6a/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/rdd/AbstractCassandraJoin.scala#L202-L212) for controlling the execution of many
asynchronous requests